# How Do I make it where only an Admin or a Manager User type can see a Navigation Link

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do is have it where the links are hidden from regualr users, and it will check to see what the users type is, if its an admin or a manager level it will display certain links example:

```
<a href="adminarea.php"> Admin Only </a>
```

Where only a User type admin is able to see the link above and also the link below in the navigation bar or a Manager is able to see only the Managers only link.

```
<a href="manager.php"> Managers Only </a>
```

This is what will show the Users Type I only have three user types, Admin, Manager and User levels.

```
 <?php echo $_SESSION['user']['user_type'];?>
```

This is what I have Right Now where only a Logged in user is able to view these Links Below:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user']['username'])){
    echo "
        <li class='nav-item dropdown'>
        <a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href='#' id='navbarDropdownMenuLink' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i>
        Admin/Managment
        </a>
        <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='navbarDropdownMenuLink'>
        <a class='nav-link' href='managment/login.php'>Managment Login</a>
        <a class='nav-link' href='admin/login.php'>Admin Login</a> 
        </div>
        </li>
        ";

echo "   </li>
    <li class='nav-item'>
    <a class='nav-link' href='logout.php'><i class='fa fa-power-off'></i> Logout</a>
    </li>";

}else{
}
?>
```

Any Ideas on how I'm able to make this happen? Thank You In Advance!

Comment: Is `$_SESSION['user']['user_type']` a String? I'm asking because I usually set these as integers because I link them as IDs of another table which lets me retrieve information about the specific User Type, which is useful when you need a tool to manage the User Types. Anyway, all 2 answers below are pretty much correct in terms of execution, but you'll have to replace some things with the values you are actually working with. In any case, if you understand how PHP works, either of the answers will be enough for you.

Comment: Do you have a table set up in your db for php to check for user, manager, admin if so we need to know the id of each to do the check?

Comment: Yes I have DB for php that is how it will check to see if the user is an Admin or Manager. `<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['user_type'];?>` will retrieve the users type and display its an Admin, Manager or User.

Comment: For an admin is the output of `<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['user_type'];?>` exactly `admin`?

Comment: Yes, If in users user_type in the database is admin it will put an output of admin.

Comment: I have edited [my solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48312831/1854340) to reflect that. Give it a try.

Comment: It Works, but I will display the Admin/Manager Drop Down Button.

Comment: This Works Also, So only an Admin Can view it`if ($_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'admin') {
        echo "
            <li class='nav-item dropdown'>
   <a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href='#' id='navbarDropdownMenuLink' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i>
Admin/Managment
   </a>
   <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='navbarDropdownMenuLink'>
<a class='nav-link' href='managment/login.php'>Managment Login</a>
   <a class='nav-link' href='admin/login.php'>Admin Login</a> 
 </div>
 </li>
";
 }`

Comment: I edited my solution again to only show the dropdown if admin or manager.

Comment: Ahh ok! I came up with a Solution for it. Thank You for the Help!! @SailorJ , Zeke and Kavinda Jayakody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user']['username'])){
    if (($_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'admin')||($_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'manager')){
        if ($_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'admin') {
            $link = "<a class='nav-link' href='admin/login.php'>Admin Login</a>";
        } elseif ($_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'management') {
            $link = "<a class='nav-link' href='managment/login.php'>Managment Login</a>";
        }
            echo "
                <li class='nav-item dropdown'>
                <a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href='#' id='navbarDropdownMenuLink' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i>
                Admin/Managment
                </a>
                <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='navbarDropdownMenuLink'>".$link."
                </div>
                </li>
                ";

echo "</li>
    <li class='nav-item'>
    <a class='nav-link' href='logout.php'><i class='fa fa-power-off'></i> Logout</a>
    </li>";
}
}else{
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check the user type and then use if else statement to display what's needed.

Here's my edit to your code....

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user']['username'])){
    echo "
        <li class='nav-item dropdown'>
        <a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href='#' 
          id='navbarDropdownMenuLink' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i>
        Admin/Managment
        </a>
        <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='navbarDropdownMenuLink'> ";
?>
<?php
        if ($_SESSION['user']['username'] == 'Admin'){
?>
        <a class='nav-link' href='managment/login.php'>Managment Login</a>
<?php 
        } elseif ($_SESSION['user']['username'] == 'Manager'){
?>
            <a class='nav-link' href='admin/login.php'>Admin Login</a>
<?php 
        } 
?> 
</div>
</li>
";

    echo "   </li>
        <li class='nav-item'>
        <a class='nav-link' href='logout.php'><i class='fa fa-power-off'></i> Logout</a>
        </li>";
}else{

}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried running this code? your else falls out of PHP code!

Comment: @AaA you meant the last "else {" part right? I just kept it as it is in the question because BigFellaHQ may have some plans to do on it. (It runs when the session don't contain a user type - obviously the user don't logged in.

Comment: try copying it into a php file and run it. you have a close tag before `";` and your last close tag does not have an open tag